# All elementor codes are showing on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

[All elementor codes are showing on WordPress page. When I am going to the main page, then I saw every single codes their then the page. Before heading their showing codes, Before menu their showing codes. How can I fix those problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFTvs.jpg)

Comment: Enable Elementor?

Comment: disable file optimization in wp-rocket?